# Is the Alternative Payment Arrangements, Managed Payment To Landlord supposed to be a way to garnish a claimants benefits without consent?

Tags: united-kingdom, social-welfare, housing

[It is in the news that someone died and was not found for years](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-65055405).  She was not found when the rent stopped being paid because of the Alternative Payment Arrangements, Managed Payment To Landlord scheme:

> After Sheila died, her rent stopped being paid, so Peabody sent letters, emails and left voicemails. But in the following year, no-one visited to check up on her. This is despite her always paying her rent on time since she'd moved into the flat in 2014.
>
> Instead, without having spoken to Sheila, Peabody applied for universal credit to be paid directly to it on her behalf. It did this via a government scheme called Alternative Payment Arrangements, which is intended for tenants struggling to pay their bills.
>
> Its application was successful, which meant by March - seven months after Sheila had died - her rent was being paid in benefits from the Department of Work and Pensions directly to Peabody.

[The guidance for this scheme is here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/universal-credit-alternative-payment-arrangements/alternative-payment-arrangements#managed-payment-to-landlord).  It talks a lot about this being for the benefit of the claimant, while noting that the landlord can make the application:

> It is important that claimants are able to make the same sorts of decisions as those in work and develop the financial capability to do so. The purpose of this guidance sets out the department’s approach to provide Alternative Payment Arrangements (APA) where appropriate for Universal Credit claimants who cannot manage their single monthly payment.
>
> This is part of the conversation Universal Credit staff will have with the claimant at the start of the claim.
>
> Social landlords who are appointed under the Trusted Partner scheme, will also have conversations with their tenants at the start of their Universal Credit claim.
>
> If a tenant has accrued rent arrears to the value of 2 months’ rent or more, their current landlord can request a rent arrears deduction.

However from the story it seems there is no conversation with the claimant, and landlords are doing this completely on their own volition if the rent is late.  Is that how it's supposed to work, or is something going wrong with the implementation?

Comment: I think that the word intended in the title is "garnish" rather than "garner" but I'm not 100% sure that this was what was intended.

Comment: Voting not to close - Questions on how a government policy is implemented is perfectly valid here as it can be factually answered.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, [the purpose of a system is what it does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_purpose_of_a_system_is_what_it_does). If the system helps landlords get free money, that's its purpose. As Wikipedia says "there's no point in claiming that the purpose of a system is to do what it constantly fails to do"

Answer (score 2):

According to the process outlined on that page, when the landlord requests activation of the alternative arrangements the decision is made by a caseworker based on the record, and then notified (if successful) to the landlord and the claimant. For a claimant without a working phone contact, the method they would be informed by would probably be by letter. The conversations in this case would expected to happen when the claimant first applied for Universal Credit.

So in short, yes one option in the scheme is to allow benefit payments to vulnerable people to be redirected to pay rent, with the justification that losing their housing would make their situation worse than the advantage of allowing them to practice control of their finances. In terms of what went most obviously wrong here, the lack of contact should have been investigated more fully, but that would be done by the police rather than the caseworker, and since in this case miscommunication meant a missed police visit was reported to the landlord as a successful one, no one followed up.

Answer (score 2):

You could call it a garnishment, but perhaps a better characterization is a minimally intrusive financial guardianship a.k.a. a conservatorship, with the government making purely non-discretionary payments on behalf of the beneficiary to avoid the hardship that the beneficiary would suffer (often for mere bureaucratic incompetence of an otherwise self-reliant and independent elderly person) that would have to be addressed with further benefits from the government, while still leaving the beneficiary tenant free to make discretionary uses of funds.

It is, of course, a sad commentary on society, that non-payment of rent is one of the only warning signals that the British have in place to determine that an elderly woman has died. But a few excess rent benefit payments are perhaps an acceptable cost for society to pay for maximizing the autonomy and independence of millions of similarly situated people.

Comment: From a quick google guardianship / conservatorship are usually court appointed, and seem to require significant incapacity.  Can these be appointed without any interaction with the "beneficiary"?

Comment: @User65535 The policy is neither a true conservatorship nor a true garnishment. The point is that if you want to draw analogies, an analogy to a very limited conservatorship might be a better one than an analogy to a garnishment.